# How to Filter Two ng-module Values in a Table using Angularjs Filter?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How can I filter two `ng-module` values in a table.[My Plunker without filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FvtRYW4CVKRFm6NSEwt?p=preview) and [My Plunker with filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/v32FaczhpTMEj5T83CGP?p=preview).

- I want to filter two ng-module value in a table.
- I can able to filter single ng-module values like using of this `| filter:{raised: 'true'}` in ng-repeat.
- I can't able to filter the two ng- module values, if I have use this `| filter:{raised: 'true'}` in ng-repeat.
- what I am Excatly looking for :- if `raised` value is `true` means these true  values only need to display in a table so that I have used `| filter:{raised: 'true'}` filter in ng-repeat.
- If `raised_two` value is also `true` means I should need to display these `true` values in a table so that I have used `| filter:{raised_two: 'true'}` filter in ng-repeat..
- But if we used two `ng-module` filters in `ng-repeat` the table is displaying like `empty` .... so how can I filter two `ng-module` valuse in a table....
- I want to display `true` values of `raised` module and `raised_two` module in table.

**My Filters:-**

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in  srdebitnote | filter:{raised: 'true'} ">

 <tr ng-repeat="data in  srdebitnote | filter:{raised_two: 'true'} ">
```

**My html:-**

```
 **<tr ng-repeat="data in  srdebitnote | filter:{raised: 'true'} ">
           <td> {{data.buyer_name}}</td>
            <td> {{data.supplier_name}}</td>
            <td> {{data.proforma_invoice_no}}</td>
            <td> {{data.purchase_order_no}}</td>
            <td> {{data.raised}}</td>
            <td> {{data.raised_two}}</td>
        </tr>**
```

**My controller:-**

```
 $scope.srdebitnote = [{
    "_id": "57db960f6a3b14d20dfb39d6",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-09-16T06:49:51.970Z",
    "shipment_id": "57c815a89a9b487f14b40bab",
    "raised_two": true,
    "raised": false,
    "invoice_number": "E21_56",
    "proforma_invoice_no": "6 years",
    "purchase_order_no": "8888",
    "supplier_name": "veena",
    "buyer_name": "risha"
    },

    {
    "_id": "57daa24fafebd11818b55d94",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-09-15T13:29:51.398Z",
    "shipment_id": "57c815a89a9b487f14b40bab",
    "raised_two": true,
    "raised": false,
    "invoice_date": "2016-09-13",
    "invoice_number": "E21_56",
    "proforma_invoice_no": "6 years",
    "purchase_order_no": "8888",
    "supplier_name": "rubi",
    "buyer_name": "kanishka"
    },

    {
    "_id": "57becb6ddc4a44520ac628f4",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-08-25T10:41:49.133Z",
    "shipment_id": "57becb69dc4a44520ac628f3",
    "raised_two": false,
    "raised": true,
    "invoice_number": "E21_check",
    "proforma_invoice_no": "kdkdkd",
    "purchase_order_no": "1356",
    "supplier_name": "karikalan",
    "buyer_name": "ms"
    },

    {
    "_id": "57bdaa65ecc4b1701401fce4",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-09-15T13:29:51.398Z",
    "shipment_id": "57c815a89a9b487f14b40bab",
    "raised_two": false,
    "raised": true,
    "invoice_date": "2016-09-13",
    "invoice_number": "E21_56",
    "proforma_invoice_no": "6 years",
    "purchase_order_no": "8888",
    "supplier_name": "rubi",
    "buyer_name": "kanishka"
    }];
```

**If i Used filter like this datas showing like empty in table:-**

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in  srdebitnote | filter:{raised: 'true'} | filter:{raised_two: 'true'} ">
```

- I have created plunker to reference :- [My Plunker without filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FvtRYW4CVKRFm6NSEwt?p=preview) and [My Plunker with filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/v32FaczhpTMEj5T83CGP?p=preview). then [My Plunker Used filter but datas showing like empty](http://plnkr.co/edit/Co2I7fUiyuKW3SarOaKs?p=preview)

Comment: if any one condition is true you want to display that table record?? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Thanks for your comment Yes exactly...

Comment: you can do one thing write custom filter which will accept parameter either you want to filter by raised or raised_two and show data accordingly

Comment: Selvam you can pass them at the time of any event for  eg- onClick of header for which column you want to filter the data

Comment: Hey thanks Mr. Dhiraj can you able to provide the updated plunker as well to know the solution...

Comment: trying i will revert back to you

Comment: yeah please?...

Comment: Can you please kindly go through the link http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp

Comment: you will find an example for filter on table header click at the bottom if page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own filter for this like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in  srdebitnote | filter: raised">

//Controller
 $scope.raised = function(item){
    if (raised.raised && raised.raised_two){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 };
```

If you want to do an `OR` instead of an `AND`, then you can filter for *either* condition to be true.

Working Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/a1TvHxgVZrncXUQhJjOI?)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I have tried this in my localhost but ,it's not working perfectly...any other idea?

Comment: What're you running into? The Plunkr provided is working perfectly. If you could post what error/issue you're encountering, I can help out further

Comment: @DustinToothless you are showing data in table either column value is true in that case you will not require any filter

Comment: @DustinToothless i have checked your plunker and i removed filter from it still i am getting same result

Comment: Could you check now @PrashantPatil. I've updated the filter name. Please excuse the typo

Comment: @PrashantPatil and no, if you remove the filter you _won't_ get the same result, you'll get the superset

Comment: @DustinToothless oops it means need to show result when both are true

Comment: @DustinToothless i interpreted question as show result with either or condition

Answer (score 0):

Hello Your problem is quite interesting. as per @Dhiraj comments above i thought the answer could be

```
         <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Buyer</td>
                        <td>Supplier</td>
                        <td>Invoice_Date</td>
                        <td>Term</td>
                        <td ng-click="data.raised=true; data.raised_two=false">Raised</td>
                         <td ng-click="data.raised_two=true; data.raised=false"> raised two</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in  srdebitnote|filter:data">
                       <td> {{data.buyer_name}}</td>
                        <td> {{data.supplier_name}}</td>
                        <td> {{data.proforma_invoice_no}}</td>
                        <td> {{data.purchase_order_no}}</td>
                        <td> {{data.raised}}</td>
                        <td> {{data.raised_two}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have set the click event on both colomn on which you want to filter the data
        and set the flag variable true and false accordingly
        You just need to add ng-click events on both columns and filter in ng-repeat and pass the flag variable to filter it will work like charm